# $r \in R$ such that $r$ cannot be written as a product of irreducible elements $a,b \in R$. Prove $r$ is irreducible and $r = bd, b, d \notin R^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be an integral domain.

Let $r \in R - R^*$ be an element, such that $r$ cannot be written as a product of irreducible elements $a,b \in R$.

Prove that $r$ is irreducible and that $r = bd, b, d \notin R^*$ where $R^*$ denote the set of units of $R$.

My idea: $r$ cannot be written as a product of irreducible elements imply that $r = bd$, where $b$ or $d$ is not irreducible. Suppose $b$ is not irreducible, then $r=jkd$, $j, k$ are non-units. Since $r=j(kd)$ and $kd\notin R^*$ this means $r$ is not irreducible and can be written as $j(kd)$ - a unit is irreducible imply $j$ is not a unit.

What if $r$ cannot be factored except $r=1r$, then $r$ is irreducible ? So we are looking at $r \in R$ that has non-trivial factorization ?

Thanks

Comment: If $r=bd$ is a product of two non-units, it is reducible (and not irreducible). I am not sure what you want to prove.

Comment: This is something from a proof that in a pricipal ideal domain every $r \in R $ has a factorization as a product of irreducible elements.

Suppose $r$ cannot be factored as a product of irreducible elements. Prove that $r$ is irreducible and that $r=bd, b, d \notin R^*$

Comment: updated: $r \in R - R^*$

Comment: Yes, in a PID its true, because a PID is Noetherian. In general, it is false. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297271/does-any-integral-domain-contain-an-irreducible-element.