# Is there an integral domain such that none of its irreducible elements is prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

> Is there some integral domain such that none of its irreducible elements is prime?

Recall that a nonzero, non invertible element $a$ of an integral domain $D$ is said to be

- *Irreducible*, if for all $b,c\in D$ such that $a=bc$, then either $b$ or $c$ is a unit in $D$.
- *Prime*, if for all $b,c\in D$ such that $a$ divides $bc$, then either $a$ divides $b$ or $a$ divides $c$.

Clearly prime implies irreducible. The converse is not true in general, but is valid when $D$ is a UFD. Obviously these notions are vacuously equivalent if $D$ has not irreducible elements (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297271/does-any-integral-domain-contain-an-irreducible-element) for examples).

Summarizing, I want to know if there is some integral domain with at least one irreducible element, but without prime elements.

Comment: An integral domain without prime elements is a field.  I think that you don't call units irreducible.  So it's impossible to have irreducible elements without primes.

Comment: @Gaffney: can you give a proof?

Comment: It's true that an integral domain with no prime ideals is a field (actually, I don't even have proof of this much weaker statement but it seems plausible). But can't it happen that a ring has only non-principal prime ideals therefore having no primes?

Comment: @Marek:  I'm mistaken; this is probably not true.

Comment: Ah, a domain without non-trivial prime ideals must contain no non-trivial ideals at all (since every ideal is contained in a maximal ideal which is prime) and thus be a field. So we're indeed looking for rings having only non-principal prime ideals.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found [this paper](http://www.shsu.edu/~stc008/finalomega.pdf) which in Example 2.2 (d) (page 4) claims that $K[[X^2,X^3]]$ is an integral domain with no prime elements but many irreducible elements, for any field $K$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $ $ The irreducibles of $\,\Bbb Q+x\Bbb R[[x]]\,$ are $\,rx\ne 0,\,r\in \Bbb R.\,$ But $\,rx\mid (\pi rx)^2,\,\ rx\nmid \pi r x\,$ by $\,\pi\not\in\Bbb Q$

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I do not have the rep to comment on your answer above, but I just wanted to point out that this example is very similar to another interesting example of factorization properties.

Looking at $R=\mathbb{R}[X^2,X^3]$.  It is atomic in the sense that every non-zero non-unit has a factorization into irreducibles, but the lengths of these factorizations can vary.  This would be impossible for a factorization into primes.  In a domain, if an element has two prime factorizations, they must be unique up to rearrangement and associate.

Consider the factorizations of the element $X^6=X^2\cdot X^2 \cdot X^2 = X^3 \cdot X^3$ are two factorizations into irreducibles.  The first of length 3 and the second of length 2.  ($X^3$ and $X^2$ are irreducible since $X \notin R$).  This is an example of a bounded factorization domain which fails to be a half factorization domain.